# Target Architecture not defined error

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

I am developing a filter driver and encountering following error:

fatal error C1189: #error :   "No target architecture defined"

```
1>Compiling...
1>miniport.c
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\inc\ddk\wdm.h(14197) : fatal error C1189: #error :   "No target     architecture defined"
1>protocol.c
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\inc\ddk\wdm.h(14197) : fatal error C1189: #error :   "No target architecture defined"
1>vwifi.c
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.0\inc\ddk\wdm.h(14197) : fatal error C1189: #error :   "No target architecture defined"
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\DriverMiniport\checked\BuildLog.htm"
1>DriverMiniport - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Xearinox you think i haven't done that... none of solution i found was working

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the target (x86, x64 etc.) for the DDK compiler. It should be done by running the `setenv.bat` script (found in the DDK) with the desired parameters. Read more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ff554139(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

right click solution and go to command line option C/C++ and add /D *X86*  in Additional options and apply. /D under score X86 under score...